# ExoPlayer hangs in SimpleExoPlayer.release( )

Tags: android

exoplayer r2.5.4
Android target sdk 22

Calling SimpleExoPlayer.release() from onDestroy of my activity. It hangs and causes ANR. I am seeing this in release builds but not debug builds, so it is proving a bit more difficult to figure out.

Does anyone have any ideas how to prevent this?

TIA

Comment: Several reports of this on Exoplayer GitHub page, but Google keep closing the tickets and ignoring them without any steps taken towards fixing this. It is a fairly common issues as you can see at: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=anr